# implementing azure group based access in an MVC5 app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm new to azure active directory and I'm trying to implement a group based access mechanism in my mvc5 (C#) app.  I have the Azure side sorted, my users are assigned to groups but I want to be able to determine which group they are in to control access to areas within the web app.  (similar to  roles based access)
so I need something like this

```
if (User.IsInGroup("Admin") || User.IsIngroup("Creator"))
        {
            //do something here
        }
```

there are only 2 groups so I don't really need roles.  I've looked at a few options using the graph api and they seem like massive overkill for what I'm trying to achieve.  Whats the best way to implement this ? Do I need to implement the graph API ? Id appreciate any advice

Comment: What would you like to receive as answer ?

Comment: what a strange comment

Comment: Strange questions ll get strange comments though. You are evaluating the API against your requirement & expecting shortcut. Graph API or group claims means a lot, but your OP & below comment for Nan answer is vague.. SO will expect some problem & work towards answer.. so I asked.. got it?

Comment: my question couldnt be any clearer

Comment: ive solved the problem now anyway

Comment: Good, can you post your answer - so it will help the future users with same thoughts..

Answer (score 1):

You could enable Group Claims in Azure AD app,  that will makes it simple to enable access management using AD groups. To enable your application to receive group claims :

1.In your application page, click on "Manifest" to open the inline manifest editor.

2.Edit the manifest by locating the "groupMembershipClaims" setting, and setting its value to "All" (or to "SecurityGroup" if you are not interested in Distribution Lists).

3.Save the manifest.

Then when user login , you will get the groups information in token ,but it will return the object id of group(that is unique identity, group name could be changed).Please click [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles/) and [here](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/authorization-cloud-applications-using-ad-groups/) for more details , also see the new groups claim sample published in the Azure AD samples github repo: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet

Please let me know if it helps .

Comment: thanks for the advice, the azure side is alreday sorted and I get the groups information in the claims token.  I had already looked at the sample in the github repo, it just seemd quite long winded to achieve something so simple.  Ill revisit it though

Comment: Yes , with group claims you doesn't need to call microsoft graph api . In addition , if this reply helps , please accept as answer , which could help others who meet same problem.

Comment: i dont seem to have any option to accept as an answer

Comment: @proteus , please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for how to accept as answer .